# Express-Session Cookie not showing up in Chrome

Tags: express-session, cookie-httponly

We are trying to get express-session to work in our App, currently for our login endpoint, I see that express session is returning the expected Cookie, it matches what is in the Sessions Store
[image: Network Tab]

But I never see it on the Application Screen in the Cookie section for my localhost.
[image]

Is there something we are doing wrong or should do further on the client side to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Had to add to our coors object `{ credentials: true }` on the server and the fetch request on the client `{ credentials: 'include' }`